# REST API rights/roles management

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm actually building a RESTFul API node.js based and I m facing a problem.

The domain code is written, and I m now trying to manage access rights on this application and I dont know how to process.

In fact, I need to allow / restrict a ressource access on a user. Actually, I've thought about storing the rights in an array in the user like this :

```
{
   userName:"foo",
   userMail:"foo@bar.com",
   userApiRightsAllowed:[
      {
         uri:"/site/1594656",
         verb:"post",
      },
      {
         uri:"/sites",
         verb:"get",
      }
   ]
}
```

In a custom middleware, I check if the user rights contains the req.url and the req.verb.

If it's okay, he can access the ressource. In the other case, he get a 403 FORBIDDEN.

**The problem**

The problem is when I need to get /sites . I authorized the user to get /sites, but he doesn't have the accesses to look at a site detail like /sites/65982 .

But in my list of sites, he will see all the sites and /sites/65982 in it.

**Question**

What is the best way of managing access rights on an API at the smallest granularity : the resource and the method ?

How can I do to make my code work, and that the user could see only the sites he's able to look at ?

*EDIT : I'm working with a MongoDb database*

Thanks in advance

Comment: So using your example configuration, when user _foo_ is requesting `/sites`, only `/site/1594656` should end up in there? Do the database records refer to the user to which a site belongs in any way?

Comment: I dont have anyrelation between the user and an other collection to manage rights. I want to avoid this, too many config in this domain

Comment: If a site can belong to only one user, it sounds like adding a user id to the site documents as a foreign-key-type relationship is a relatively easy solution, though. Otherwise, for each endpoint you need to postprocess the data coming from the database to make it fit the access that the user has.

Comment: The fact is the user is on one-many sites. Then, there are others child informations to manage and they are not related to the parent. I have 6 child level to handle in this case, and have to modify every request to check the user rights

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `express` (based on the tag), [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) is a great option for extending the functionality of your app beyond the basic REST functionality that express gives you. Sails has some useful addons for helping with management of roles, users, and permissions:

- [sails-permissions](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions)
- [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth)

Comment: I'd recommend [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth) as well.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good one. sails-auth is based on sails-generate-auth